# How can I invite a user to a chat?

Tags: support, chat

I want to invite a certain user to a chat to avoid writing more and more comments on a post, how do I do it?

Comment: [meta.se]: [How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57537) and [math.meta.se]: [How do I invite a user to chat?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22037)  These posts have some screenshots, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user has a chat account, go to their profile and click on the "start a new room with this user" button there.

If they don't have a chat user, you can't invite them to chat. Moderators have a way to do that, but that is not meant for this kind of situation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can only do this via a comment that links to the chat. I think it's a shame that we have to use a comment to do this, but at least it's a comment that doesn't invite further discussion.

If they've already been a participant in a particular chat, then they will be notified by @ messages in that chat.

You can also invite a user to a room via their chat.stackexchange.com profile page: [Inviting a user to chat from the profile page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126100/inviting-a-user-to-chat-from-the-profile-page)

Comment: @notifying them in chat will only work if they were recently in that chat room (not sure about the exact threshold, a few days I think).